# как скачать нормальный питон?

Tags: python

Когда я скачал питон, у меня появился питон в командной строке и питон IDLe, но когда я смотрел видео как скачать питон я видел полноценную красивую и удобную программу. Как скачать этот питон? Я смогу скинуть скриншот того питона.

Comment: "Тот питон", вероятно, как-то назывался. И был это не сам Питон, а какая-то IDE для него. Самая популярная – PyCharm, как Вам уже подсказал @ppontmercy

Comment: питон это язык программирования. программа которую вы скачали скорее всего является интерпретатором и да, она выполняется в командной строке и когда говорят о питоне в контексте программы имеют в виду именно это.  А то что Вы видели где-то на ютубе питоном никак являться не может, но вполне себе может являться инструментом для работы с ним.

Answer (score 3):

Если полноценная и красивая программа, то
https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/pycharm/

Выбирай Community версию!

Comment: я перехожу по ссылке и она не грузится. Всё другое грузится очень хорошо

Comment: @xL1tez_ Выбираете вашу платформу, нажимаете Скачать под Community, и если не начинается скачивание можно нажать на `воспользуйтесь прямой ссылкой`

Comment: @xL1tez_ загуглите "Скачать PyCharm" да и всё